# What is the meaning of ぬ in the song ミルクムナリ? (Not the archaic auxiliary verb ぬ)

Tags: grammar, meaning, particles, song-lyrics, ryukyuan-languages

Call me crazy, but I am trying to translate [ミルクムナリ](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pCflmiwaAXg), which is common played in Taiko performances, at least in Okinawa; the song is very archaic, as it speaks of a king from the turn of the 16th century. At the moment, I have been able to find some interpretative work on some aspects of the song ([lyrics are available here](https://www.uta-net.com/song/150723/), [an general explanation of the lyrics is provided here](https://taru.ti-da.net/e759857.html)), but what I have noticed throughout the song is the use of ぬ, and yet I am unsure what it is supposed to mean. Here is the first line:

> コドゥシミルクヌ　ユガフドゥシサミ

Which means

> 今年弥勒ぬ、豊穣年さみ

I am still trying to determine what さみ is, but the focus for this question is on ぬ: it is not a conjugation of a verb (弥勒, or みろく in modern spelling, is not a verb), so immediately most information I have found has not helped. Can anyone try to provide me some context? It would help since it is used in almost all parts of the song, as said.

Comment: Quick note on the tags -- you'd added the tag for Old Japanese. I just changed that to the tag for the Ryukyuan languages. Old Japanese refers to mainland Japanese from the start of Japanese writing until only the year 794 or so. See also [the Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old_Japanese#Sources_and_dating). Since the text you're working with is from the 1500s, and it's from Okinawa and not mainland Japan, this can't be Old Japanese. :) [HTH](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/HTH)!

Comment: [インドネシア語の踊るを意味するムナリ（menari）](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9F%E3%83%AB%E3%82%AF%E3%83%A0%E3%83%8A%E3%83%AA)

Comment: @sundowner Maybe; [Ryukyu Kingdom did have trade relations with Indonesia.](http://rca.open.ed.jp/web_e/history/story/epoch2/daikoeki_4.html) I suppose "Dance" would apply to King Ganashi, since the authors of this song saw him as a god.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One sense of ぬ in various 琉球語 varieties simply corresponds to の.

While I don't know for sure what さみ is, *if* we assume it is a copula like だ, then the sentence would be something like

> 今年弥勒の豊穣年だ

which seems straightforward to interpret.

弥勒{みろく} is a Buddhist deity ([Maitreya Buddha](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%BC%A5%E5%8B%92%E8%8F%A9%E8%96%A9)), or the Buddha of the future to come.

EDIT: [This page](https://taru.ti-da.net/e619390.html) claims that さみ means 〜なのだよ, which would fit perfectly with the above guess.

Comment: +1 for Jogloran's findings.  See also [the JLect page for サミ](https://www.jlect.com/search.php?r=%E3%81%95%E3%81%BF&l=ryukyu&group=words), particularly the third entry down in the blue section for the _Okinawago jiten dētā shū_, which defines this as 「…なのだぞ。…なんだよ。」. See also [the JLect page for ぬ](https://www.jlect.com/search.php?r=%E3%81%AC&l=ryukyu&group=words), the first entry in that same blue section.

Comment: Yo that is a wicked website; never knew it existed. Thank you.